# Metapost: pass 2D array in vardef

Tags: arrays, metapost

Can we pass 2D array in `vardef`? Followed is a small code. It failed to compile.

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 3;
input boxes

beginfig(1)

vardef table (expr upper_left_centre, row, col, data) =
  label(data[0][0], upper_left_centre);
enddef;

string data[][];
% title
data[0][0] := "Wall height";

table (origin, 2, 6, data);

endfig;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you can declare this array as a *suffix* parameter.

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 3;

beginfig(1)

vardef table (expr upper_left_centre)(suffix data) =
  label(data[0][0], upper_left_centre);
enddef;

string data[][];
% title
data[0][0] := "Wall height";

table (origin, data);

endfig;

end.
```

[image]

Quoting the [MetaPost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf), p. 56:

> If you just want to pass a variable name to a macro, it is better to
>   declare it as a suffix parameter. For example,
>
> ```
> def incr(suffix $) = begingroup $:=$+1; $ endgroup enddef;
> ```
>
> defines a macro that will take any numeric variable, add one to it,
>   and return the new value.

Comment: Read the manual many times but ignore the point `"Text parameters are very general, but their generality sometimes gets in the way. If you just want to pass a variable name to a macro, it is better to declare it as a suffix parameter."`. But the `suffix` generally makes me confusing. I don't know when I should use. Sometimes by guess. Thanks @ Franck

Comment: Indeed it can ben confusing.  I reckon that`suffix` is to be used when you need to manipulate a variable (or more generally a suffix name), e.g. to increment it if it is a numeric. The parameters given as `expr` are to be used as such, they can't be changed.

Comment: The difference is in the expansion. `expr` variables are expanded before they are passed to the macro. `text` and `suffix` are not. `suffix` has a limited range of allowed characters, `text` is more general, with for example, `,` allowed.

Comment: @Thruston Thanks for this. It is much clearer than the MetaPost manual's explanations! :-)