# Fit all given points in the patatoid

Tags: metapost, metafun

I am trying to adapt this [metapost patatoid generator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646320/213111) to fit a list of pairs given to [a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406464/213111).
To that purpose I [loop through the list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560682/213111) of pairs and determine the greatest `x` and `y` distances between all points with their coordinates. Then, I the the patatoid generator with the given `width` and `height` and shift it at the lowest coordinates to fit (almost) them all.

```tex
def drawlistofpoints(suffix p) =
  numeric i ; i := 0 ;
  forever:
    if known p[i]:
      drawdot p[i] withpen pencircle scaled 3pt ;
      i := i+1 ;
    fi ;
    exitif unknown p[i] ;
  endfor ;
enddef ;


vardef patatoid(expr w,h,x,y) =
  hide(
    numeric i,maxi,maxd ; i:=0; maxd := 0 ;
    numeric dist[] ;
    pair tmpp[] ;
    path sq, p ;
    sq := unitsquare xyscaled (w,h) shifted (x, y) ;
    for i = 0 upto 3:
        tmpp[i] := point (i + uniformdeviate(1)) of sq ;
    endfor ;
    tmpp[4] := tmpp[0] ;
    for i= 0 upto 3 :
        dist[i] := abs(tmpp[i+1] - tmpp[i]) ;
        if (dist[i] > maxd) :
            maxd := dist[i] ;
            maxi := i ;
        fi ;
    endfor ;
    p := for i = 0 upto maxi : tmpp[i] .. endfor (uniformdeviate(1))[tmpp[maxi],tmpp[maxi+1]] for i = maxi + 1 upto 3: .. tmpp[i] endfor .. cycle ;
  )
  p
enddef ;


def drawset(suffix p)=
  numeric i,w,h,lx,hx,ly,hy; i:=0; w:=0; h:=0; lx:=0; hx:=0; ly:=0; hy:=0;
  numeric offset ; offset = 2cm ;
  forever:
    if known p[i]: % this is a naive approach
      if (xpart p[i]) < lx: lx := (xpart p[i]); fi
      if (xpart p[i]) > hx: hx := (xpart p[i]); fi
      if (ypart p[i]) < ly: ly := (ypart p[i]); fi
      if (ypart p[i]) > hy: hy := (ypart p[i]); fi
      i:=i+1;
    fi
    exitif unknown p[i];
  endfor ;
  hx := hx+offset ; lx := lx-offset ; hy := hy+offset ; ly := ly-offset ;
  w := abs(hx - lx) ; h := abs(hy - ly) ;

  draw patatoid(w,h,lx,ly) withpen pencircle scaled 1pt ;
  drawlistofpoints(p) ;
enddef ;
```

However, if a point have "unusual" coordinates and is not packed with the others it will finish outside of the patatoid:

```tex
\startTEXpage
  \startMPcode
    pair a,b,c,d,e,f, g,h;
    a := (0.5cm,0.75cm) ; b := (1.5cm,0.75cm) ; c := (2.5cm,0.75cm) ;
    d := (0.5cm,2.25cm) ; e := (1.5cm,2.25cm) ; f := (2.5cm,2.25cm) ;
    g := (2.25cm,4.5cm) ; h := (-1.5cm,-0.75cm) ;

    pair points[];
    points[0] := a ;
    points[1] := b ;
    points[2] := c ;
    points[3] := d ;
    points[4] := e ;
    points[5] := f ;
    points[6] := g ;
    points[7] := h ;

    drawset(points) ;
  \stopMPcode
\stopTEXpage
```

How can I make sure to fit them all?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the patatoid is clearly not covering the rectangle that it is defined from, so you will have to give up something. Perhaps you start from the wrong end.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Perhaps you start from the wrong end."?

Comment: If you want to construct a curve that includes points in a certain rectangle, then it looks wrong to use a curve that by its definition do not cover the rectangle. So, what are you trying to do (on a higher level, perhaps)?

Comment: Imagine a blackboard where you want to draw, maybe a bijective map, and where you have a bunch of elements (represented by points (or pairs here)) of two sets A and B. The first step (way before drawing the map arrows) is to "circle" those elements to know which ones are elements of the A set and which other ones are elements of the B set. What I want here is to fake that patatoid shape we could create by hand on the blackboard.

Comment: Well, you could start with the patatoid, and then randomly generate points and test if they are inside. Loop until you have as many points as you wish. But not sure that would give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different implementation.

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`, or adapt it to work with your Context environment.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document} 
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    pair p[];
    for i=1 upto 10:
        p[i] = 21(normaldeviate, normaldeviate);
    endfor
    
    picture dots; dots = image(
    numeric i; i = 0;
    forever:
        exitif not known p[incr i];
        draw p[i] withpen pencircle scaled 3;
    endfor);

    pair o; o = center dots;
    path spud;
    spud = for i=1/4 step 1/2 until 4:
       (5/4 + uniformdeviate 1/2)[o, point i of bbox dots] ..
    endfor cycle;

    fill spud withcolor 1/256(239, 234, 181);
    draw spud;
    draw dots;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

My approach here is

- capture 10 dots in random places as p1, p2, p3 etc
- save a drawing of all the dots as a `<picture>` variable
- then step round the bounding box of the picture using the mediation syntax to find a point a random distance *beyond* the bbox.  The expression `(5/4 + uniformdeviate 1/2)` yields a random number between 1.25 and 1.75, and since `o` is defined as the `center` of all the dots, `1.5[o, point i of bbox dots]` yields a point that *must* be beyond the bbox.
- and the clever bit is starting at point 1/4 and stepping 1/2 each time, so that we avoid the corners; this makes the random shape more potato-like.
- I found the potato color `1/256(239, 234, 181)` from searching the web.

A couple of other points of syntax:

- If `i` is numeric, then `incr i` will increment it in place.  There is also `decr i` which does the opposite.  The implementation in `plain.mp` is very clever:

  ```
    % special operators
    vardef incr suffix $ = $:=$+1; $ enddef;
    vardef decr suffix $ = $:=$-1; $ enddef;
  ```
- In Metapost (unlike in Metafont) `drawdot <pair>` is exactly equivalent to  `draw <pair>`.

#### Some more detail

What's going on in these lines?

```
path spud;
spud = for i=1/4 step 1/2 until 4:
  (5/4 + uniformdeviate 1/2)[o, point i of bbox dots] ..
endfor cycle;
```

This loop is generating the outline path for the potato shape.  (The word "spud" is British slang for a potato.)  This is an in-line loop; Metapost expands the loop as part of making the definition, so it expands into:

```
spud = (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 0.25 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 0.75 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 1.25 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 1.75 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 2.25 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 2.75 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 3.25 of bbox dots] ..
       (1.25 + uniformdeviate 0.5)[o, point 3.75 of bbox dots] .. cycle;
```

which expands into something like this (although obviously, the `uniformdeviate` calls will be different each time):

```
spud = (1.3399)[o, point 0.25 of bbox dots] ..    
       (1.7087)[o, point 0.75 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.4047)[o, point 1.25 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.4849)[o, point 1.75 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.5348)[o, point 2.25 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.3187)[o, point 2.75 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.7404)[o, point 3.25 of bbox dots] .. 
       (1.3717)[o, point 3.75 of bbox dots] .. cycle;
```

The way the mediation syntax works is that if you put `1/2[z0, z1]` you will get a point exactly 1/2 way between `z0` and `z1`, if you put `3/4[z0, z1]` the point will be 3/4 of the way from `z0` to `z1`, and so on.  But if the fraction is *greater* than 1 the point will be *beyond* `z1`, so `1.5[z0, z1]` will be "50%" beyond `z1` on the line through `z0` and `z1`, so since `o` is in the middle of the dots, each of the points in the definition of the path will make a point beyond the bbox, which will look something like this:

[image]

where the red box is the `bbox` of the dots and each red arrow points at one of the points on the `spud` path.  So the point at the lower left is 33.99% "beyond" point 0.25 of the bounding box, and so on. The neat thing is to avoid the corners.  If you can't see this then try experimenting with the start value of the loop and observe what happens.